# Golang Http Client request fails on Custom Http Status code

Tags: go, httpclient

We are rewriting an old integration with a service from python to golang. This service uses Custom status codes. For example the status code is 8000. But while I am trying to get the response it is giving me error as “malformed HTTP status code”. Can some one help me to resolve this issue. Gone through the code and found the following piece of code that throws the error if the status code is not having length of 3.

```
   if len(statusCode) != 3 {
    return nil, &badStringError{"malformed HTTP status code", statusCode}
}
```

EDIT:
I do understand the RFC standard for HTTP status is 3 digits. But I am re-integrating a legacy code of a Banking system. So I cannot / dont have the access to change the service's implementation.

To give more context, python's http library was not doing this validation.  (I am not saying that One language is superior to another, so please dont compare the languages/libraries) So wondering if there is any way to bypass this particular validation. 
Thanks in advance for understanding..

Comment: To resolve this issue you have to fix the status code. 8000 is not valid HTTP. If you cannot fix the underlying bug you cannot use package net/http's features (as you are no longer speaking HTTP): Use low level functions (e.g. in net) and reimplement what you need to handle your pseudo HTTP.

Comment: Indeed, the problem here is the status code, not `net/http`. Per the spec, HTTP status codes are all exactly 3 digits, which is why Go's client is implemented this way.

Comment: I do understand that the RFC spec says the status code has to be 3 digits. But the issue is that the service which I am trying to integrate is a very old legacy Bank api. And we dont have any control over that. Also I am not saying the issue is with the net/http. But I am asking if there is a way to bypass this validation for legacy codes.

Answer (score 1):

From RFC 2616:

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the
>      attempt

What you have there is not valid HTTP. If you can get hold of the socket directly, you could try parsing the raw TCP data.

Comment: Can you help me in understanding how to directly listen to the socket?

Comment: Strictly speaking it’s not an HTTP service because it violates basic protocol. You can make you own fork of golang http libraries and patch them. I am pretty sure nobody will accept this patch to mainstream because it means to break unknown number of clients obeying protocols. Thus you have to maintain it on your own. Fortunately patch is very little it won’t be problem. Do not forget to make your tests and make sure all standard test keep working.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish you may use standard code for general information (ok, client error, server error, etc) and custom application codes transferred in payload for more details.

Comment: The service I am integrating is not under my control to change the behaviour of the HTTP Server. The service is a legacy banking system and its tough to change a existing API from a bank's end..